# can't access shared ec2 ami : error public key denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 AMI I have shared with another account based on these instructions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html .  In the other account I launch a new instance from the shared AMI.  When I attempt to connect via ssh:

```
ssh -i mykey.pem ec2-user@my-new-instance-ip
```

I get the error:

> Permission denied (publickey).

I have done this dozens of times with other accounts and have never had an issue.

Also, I launched a regular instance not based off the shared AMI but with the same key and security group and it shared no problem.  I have also applied chmod 400 to the key.

Did something change with the process of sharing AMIs with other accounts and launching instances from them?

Comment: What is Example.com are you using the domain to ssh?

Comment: @error2007s it is the instance IP.  I pulled it straight from the connect details in the dashboard.

Comment: Are you getting error for both instances or one instance is working and another not? And in which AWS account the "mykey.pem" generated?

Comment: @error2007s I only get the error with the instance launched from the shared AMI.

Comment: When you go to the AWS dashboard click on the instance launched from AMI under description what do you see in "Key pair name"?

Comment: @error2007s I see the key: mykey.pem

Comment: Last question the instance you launched is a Ubuntu instance or AWS Linux instance?

Comment: @error2007s it is AWS linux.  Thanks a million!

Comment: Launch the AMI using a whole New pem key and see if it is working?

Comment: wild guess: are you sure you're using the public ip, not private one? Chances your office network has the same sublet as VPC are small, but exist.